# Restore missing main menu

Tags: nodes, navigation, configuration

I have managed to hide/lose the main menu bar - drupal 7.x.

overview of work I was doing:

- I added mediaelements.js
- I began adding videos to the site with add content
- I attempted to make a Videos menu in the main menu

It was during some point of this process that I noticed the main menu bar was missing.
I have searched SE for solutions similar to  mine and have not had success with what was presented as solutions (having main menu in block and appearance settings toggled).
I have, so far, tried to go through each setting and compared them against settings in dev environment. 
Are their other troubleshooting tasks I should follow which may point to a resolution?

thank you

Comment: 1. Does clearing all your site's cache restore it? 2. Have you replaced the core toolbar with a contributed module? (admin_menu) 3. How are you rendering videos? From YT/uploaded yourself Reasons that are likely to make it disappear are weird cache behaviour and missing closing html element tags.

Comment: @josh - clearing the site cache did not restore.  I have not attempted suggestion 2, I will look up how to do this and give it a try.  Videos are uploaded/self hosted. -- thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved - I had restricted the main menu block to specific content types. Removing the restriction restored main menu block across all content types.